# Do I need to call get() if I use multiprocessing in python but my function does not return anything?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'd like to utilize python's multiprocessing module to parallelize this simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import h5py
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from multiprocessing import Pool

def load_array(path, variable):
    try:
        return np.array(h5py.File(path, "r").get(variable))
    except:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Corrupted file: {}".format(path))

def mat2img(rootdir, save_path, variable):

    fig = plt.figure()

    print("Processing " + rootdir)

    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            arr = load_array(os.path.join(subdir, file), variable).T

            fig.subplots_adjust(top=1, bottom=0, right=1, left=0)
            plt.pcolormesh(np.arange(0, arr.shape[1]), np.arange(0, arr.shape[0]), arr, cmap="jet")
            plt.axis("off")
            plt.savefig(os.path.join(save_path, subdir.split(os.path.sep)[-1], file + ".jpg"))
            plt.clf()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        pool.apply_async(mat2img, ("O:\\data1", "O:\\spectrograms", "spectrum"))
        pool.apply_async(mat2img, ("O:\\data2", "O:\\spectrograms", "spectrum"))
        pool.apply_async(mat2img, ("O:\\data3", "O:\\spectrograms", "spectrum"))
```

However this does nothing as if `apply_async` didn't call any function. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) I see that each `apply_async` is assigned to some variable `res`. Do I need to do the same even though my function does not return anything? If so, what would that variable `res` contain and what would I get calling `get()`? Where did I make the mistake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You schedule your jobs with `appy_async`. Then you have to wait until they complete. If you don't wait, they will not even start.

```
with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
    pool.apply_async(mat2img, ("O:\\data1", "O:\\spectrograms", "spectrum"))
    pool.apply_async(mat2img, ("O:\\data2", "O:\\spectrograms", "spectrum"))
    pool.apply_async(mat2img, ("O:\\data3", "O:\\spectrograms", "spectrum"))
    pool.close()  # Do not accept any more jobs.
    pool.join(timeout=1000)  # Wait until all async jobs complete.
```

Alternatively, you can `.get()` to make sure each job finishes:

```
with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
    # Schedule the jobs.
    jobs = [pool.apply_async(mat2img, (dest, "O:\\spectrograms", "spectrum"))
            for dest in ("O:\\data1", "O:\\data2", "O:\\data3")]
    # Wait for the jobs to complete.
    for job in jobs:
        job.get(timeout=100)
```

As @AndreaCorbellini correctly notes, you can do `job.wait()` instead of `job.get()` if your job does not return any result you care about.

Comment: So I have to call `get` regardless of whether my function does return something or not, thanks

Comment: @Colonder: yes, `.get()` means "I actually want to run this task". Sometimes you won't, e.g. when you want to stop computation early, and don't want some queued tasks to even start.

Comment: @9000: calling `.join()` without `.get()` is enough, as you noted. Tasks will be started regardless you call `.get()` or not

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: I suppose `.join()` calls `.get()` [or equivalent internally](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L543), and just ignores the results.

Comment: @9000: sort of, but what I'm trying to clarify is that [`.get()` does not start the task](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/multiprocessing/pool.py#L637)

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini: I'd say it's not the _only_ way to start the task; you can use `.wait` if you don't care about the result.  Still, without a `.get` or `.wait`, the task will not start, AFAICT. Thanks for pointing at it; I'll update my answer.

Comment: I've just tested `wait()` and it also doesn't work, only `get()`